# BigQuery Support for Youtube Data

Tags: google-bigquery, youtube, youtube-data-api, dimensions, dimension

There are many dimensions in the Youtube BigQuery data such as device_type where we don't get told was device_type = 101 actually is, this is frustrating as it is across many dimensions, operating system, traffic_source_type etc. How do I find out what the various codes actually mean?

p_channel_traffic_source_a2
p_channel_device_os_a2

I tried various pages such as

https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/dimensions#Device_Dimensions

and

https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/channel_reports#video-device-type-and-operating-system

but none actually give you what each code mean which is extremely annoying

Answer (score 0):

YouTube lists the device_type and operating system dimension values for the YouTube Reporting API  and YouTube Analytics API here:  https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/dimensions#Device_Dimensions